# Sending the contents of a union in C over a network connection

Tags: c, serialization, unions

I'm trying to understand and use a `union` in C in a Linux environment.
Suppose I have the following union

```
union test {
    int one;
    long two;
} t1;
```

If I'm going to write `t1.one` to a network file descriptor (socket fd) then extra zeros will be written to the fd as the union chooses the biggest element, which is two; and it can get even worse with a union of structures.  Can someone please show me how to overcome this?

Comment: You make a decision: you write the complete union and waste bandwidth by sending stuff that is not relevant (and it leaves you with a number of problems on the receiving end, especially if the computer types are not identical), or you do the job properly and send a serialized version of the current value of the union.  The latter is more sensible, for a large number of different reasons.

Comment: how can you do that, I'm writing test.one, that should be it, correct?

Comment: Look up serialization; there are a lot of question on SO about serialization.  Find a copy of ['The Practice of Programming'](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/index.html) by Kernighan and Pike; amongst the many useful topics they discuss is serialization and deserialization of data.

Comment: You might need to look up [TLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) (type, length, value) encodings, too.  It depends a lot on the context, and what the sender and receiver know about the data that is about to be sent.  Somehow, the receiver must know how much data of which type has been sent to it.  There are different ways of doing that, depending on the protocol chosen for communicating between sender and receiver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you write `test.one` to the network fd, you'll write exactly `sizeof (int)` bytes.  `test.one` is an `int` object; the fact that it happens to be a member of a union is irrelevant, as long as you don't access the union as a whole.

If you write the entire union, then of course you'll write the full size of the union, which will be *at least* the size of its largest member.

So don't do that.

Keep track of which member of the union is current (i.e., which member you most recently assigned a value to), and just use that member.

Then again, given the minimal information you've given us, it's not clear that it makes sense to use a union at all.

Comment: Actually I have nothing to show, I've seen this and I wanted to know how it should be done, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

An `union` has the size of the biggest element (in this case `long`), not like a structure. By changing `one` you will overwrite the first 32 bit (on 32 bit OS 16) of long, by changing `two` the whole space will be overwritten and `one` is lost.

#### `union test` on a 64 bit OS:

```
-      64 bit      +
│    union test    │
├──────────────────┤
│ long             │
├─────────┬────────┘
│ int     |
└─────────┘
```

#### `struct test` on a 64 bit OS:

```
-           96 bit           +
│         struct test        │
├──────────────────┬─────────┤
│ long             │ int     │
└──────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I'm going to write test.one to network fd then extra zeros will be written to the fd

Although it is correct that extra bytes will be written, the content of these bytes is not necessarily going to be all zeros: it is undefined. In general, reading the bytes belonging to a union that are beyond the area to which you have written some data through other fields is undefined behavior. If you want to control how much data is written, you need to provide the specific type that you are writing out.